# Radio Input with hover

Tags: css, radio-button

I am trying to add an hover to my radio boxes.
!important does not work. Is there any way to get the radio input fields hovering?
You can see the full example on jsfiddle. Tried to do that on line 39.

If you select the 5th radio box, and hover over the first one, than the other should be turn grey and the hovered orange.

```
/* Filled Rating */
.rating-fill{
    width:0;
    height:100%;
    background:url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
    position:absolute;
    background-size: contain;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
}

/* Checked Inputs */

.radio-wrap input[value="5"]:checked + .rating-fill{
    width:100%;
}

.radio-wrap input[value="4"]:checked + .rating-fill{
    width:80%;
}

.radio-wrap input[value="3"]:checked + .rating-fill{
    width:60%;
}

.radio-wrap input[value="2"]:checked + .rating-fill{
    width:40%;
}

.radio-wrap input[value="1"]:checked + .rating-fill{
    width:20%;
}


/* Blank Stars */

.rating-blank{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iMjBweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyMHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjAgMjAiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDIwIDIwIiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48cG9seWdvbiBmaWxsPSIjREREREREIiBwb2ludHM9IjEwLDAgMTMuMDksNi41ODMgMjAsNy42MzkgMTUsMTIuNzY0IDE2LjE4LDIwIDEwLDE2LjU4MyAzLjgyLDIwIDUsMTIuNzY0IDAsNy42MzkgNi45MSw2LjU4MyAiLz48L3N2Zz4=');
    position:absolute;
    background-size: contain;
    top:0;
    left:0; 
    z-index:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9q9gfob6/2/

Comment: What is the `hover` supposed to do?

Comment: If the user hovers the first radio box, than the .rating-fillig whould get an width of 20%. The first star is orange and the other four are grey.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is actually working. Because first star is already selected(width already 20% initially), hover isn't taking effect.

```
.radio-wrap input[value="5"]:hover + .rating-fill{
    width:100%;
}

.radio-wrap input[value="4"]:hover + .rating-fill{
    width:80%;
}

.radio-wrap input[value="3"]:hover + .rating-fill{
    width:60%;
}

.radio-wrap input[value="2"]:hover + .rating-fill{
    width:40%;
}

.radio-wrap input[value="1"]:hover + .rating-fill{
    width:20%;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vusan/9q9gfob6/3/)
The  fifth input is dropped so hovering on fifth star doesn't make any effect.

Comment: ok, hover is working. If radio 5 is checked and radio 1 hovered, it should only show the first star orange. and the others grey.